# Save SQL query results to a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to save my adjusted query results into a table. For example I have codes 350.8, 351.94 and I have T-SQL code to remove the decimal points resulting in the adjusted results 350,351 etc. I want to save the results into a table, not Excel. Is this possible?

I see you can create a new table but with the same columns, not the new adjusted results. The below doesn't work as SQL Server doesn't recognise adjusted1, 2 and 3.

```
CREATE TABLE DiagAdj 
(
     encounter_id NUMERIC,
     di_1 INT, 
     di_2 INT, 
     di_3 INT,
     adjusted1 INT,
     adjusted2 INT,
     adjusted3 INT,
);

INSERT INTO DiagAdj (encounter_id, adjusted1, adjusted2, adjusted3)
    SELECT encounter_id, adjusted1, adjusted2, adjusted3
    FROM dbo.Encounters
```

Decimal places removed. I want to save down adjusted3 results into a table

```
SELECT 
    encounter_id, di_3, -- now, try to cast to int the remainder, ending right before the decimal
    adjusted3 = TRY_CONVERT(int,LEFT(di_3, COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('.', di_3) - 1, -1), 255)))
FROM 
    dbo.Encounters;
```

Comment: `cast(diag_1 as integer)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just cast each decimal column to integer:

```
INSERT INTO DiagAdj (encounter_id, adjusted1, adjusted2, adjusted3)
SELECT
    encounter_id,
    CAST(diag1 AS DECIMAL(10,0)),
    CAST(diag2 AS DECIMAL(10,0)),
    CAST(diag3 AS DECIMAL(10,0))
FROM dbo.Encounters;
```

Comment: Hi, I created a table diagadj but when i use the cast as per above.  The adjusted1,adjusted2, adjusted3 causes an error.                                            
 CREATE TABLE DiagAdj 
(
  encounter_id numeric,
  diag_1 INT, 
  diag_2 int, 
  diag_3 int,
  adjusted1 int,
  adjusted2 int,
  adjusted3 int,
);

Comment: error message with cast-->Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
Invalid column name 'adjusted1'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
Invalid column name 'adjusted2'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
Invalid column name 'adjusted3'.

Comment: Then the problem is with your table.  Maybe the columns are called something else.  If `Encounters` be a view, then check the underlying view definition to make sure these columns exist.

Comment: tim,  in the encounter table i have encounter_id, diag_1,diag_2,diag_3 and with the below code i can remove the decimal place. There are no adjusted columns in the encounter table. it is the adjusted results which i want to save in a new table DiagAdj . Is this possible?

Comment: SELECT encounter_id,diag_3, 
  adjusted3 = TRY_CONVERT(int,LEFT(diag_3, COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('.',diag_3)-1,-1),255)))
FROM dbo.Encounters;

Comment: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '250.83' to data type int.
The data was exported from azure as a varchar (as it contained codes like X123 but i have since replaced the alphabetic symbol X with 999) and the destination table is int so I get an error message in sql.  If i export the file from azure and the table have numeric datatypes and update the select cast stmts to numeric ... this may work?

Comment: Try casting to `DECIMAL(10,0)`.

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
Invalid column name 'diag1'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
Invalid column name 'diag2'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 27
Invalid column name 'diag3'.

Comment: Sorted. Thank you.

Comment: @Clonew You might want to post your own answer.

Comment: Cast as int worked in the end
INSERT INTO dbo.DiagAdj (encounter_id, adjusted1, adjusted2, adjusted3, age)
SELECT
    CAST(encounter_id AS int),
    CAST(diag1 AS int),
    CAST(diag2 AS int),
    CAST(diag3 AS int),
    CAST(age AS int)
FROM dbo.Encounters;